# Apply same function to each element of N arrays of different sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, c++17

Let's consider a class `A` with a constructor and a member function `foo` implemented.

Here's some code:

```
constexpr int size1 = 100;
constexpr int size2 = 13;
constexpr int size3 = 48;
constexpr int size4 = 231;
constexpr int size5 = 5;
constexpr int size6 = 125;
constexpr int size7 = 88;
constexpr int size8 = 549;
constexpr int size9 = 417;

int main(void)
{
    std::array<A*, size1> array1;
    std::array<A*, size2> array2;
    std::array<A*, size3> array3;
    std::array<A*, size4> array4;
    std::array<A*, size5> array5;
    std::array<A*, size6> array6;
    std::array<A*, size7> array7;
    std::array<A*, size8> array8;
    std::array<A*, size9> array9;

    // Solution

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to construct each element of each array, then call the member function `foo` for each and every one of them.

Basically, I would like to do:

```
for (auto& element : array1)
{
    element = new A();
    element->foo();
}
```

for each array.

What's the shortest and easiest way to do that without writing down nine for-loops in a row?

Comment: tuple of arrays, and "iterate" over both ?

Comment: Can't you get your sizes in a tuple, or array, or span, or std::array?

Comment: I'm not as comfortable with `std::stuple` as I should be, which explains why this question was relevant to me. Three detailed and well-explained answers came up within the first 30 minutes after I clicked 'submit'. If the question was bad, nobody ever would have bothered. I don't understand the negative score.

Comment: I believe this is an XY problem.   What do you want - in term of real use cases?  e.g. what is the meaning of `A` in your program actually?   .... `std::vector` or MACRO might be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely would want to pack the code into a specific initialisation function. As (`std::`) arrays of different lengths actually are different types, though, you either need a template function or need to operate on the arrays' internal raw arrays (`data()`):

```
template <typename T>
void initialize(T& t)
{
    for(auto& a : t)
    //      ^ reference to pointer (!)
    {
        a = new A();
        a->foo();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You'd then simply call this function on every array. If that's still not short enough, you could pack this into a variadic template function:

```
template <typename T, typename ... TT>
void initialize(T& t, TT& ... tt)
{
    initialize(t);
    initialize(tt...);
}

// alternatively, a bit shorter, with C++17 fold expression:
template <typename ... TT>
void initialize(TT& ... tt)
{
    (initialize(tt), ...);
}
```

At the point of call, this would most likely be the shortest you can get (apart from selecting an even shorter name):

```
initialize(array1, array2, array3, array4, ...);
```

Comment: Possibly `(initialize(tt), ...);` as C++17

Answer (score 2):

You might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
using As = std::array<A*, N>;

std::tuple<As<size1>, As<size2>, As<size3>, As<size4>, As<size5>,
           As<size6>, As<size7>, As<size8>, As<size9>> arrays;

std::apply([](auto& ...as)
          {
              auto l = [](auto& a)
              {
                for (auto& element : a)
                {
                    element = new A();
                    element->foo();
                }
              };
              (l(as), ...);
          }, arrays);
```

Or even simpler:

```
template <size_t N>
std::array<A*, N> MakeAs()
{
    std::array<A*, N> res;
    for (auto& element : res)
    {
        element = new A();
        element->foo();
    }
    return res;
}
```

and

```
auto array1 = MakeAs<size1>();
auto array2 = MakeAs<size2>();
auto array3 = MakeAs<size3>();
auto array4 = MakeAs<size4>();
auto array5 = MakeAs<size5>();
auto array6 = MakeAs<size6>();
auto array7 = MakeAs<size7>();
auto array8 = MakeAs<size8>();
auto array9 = MakeAs<size9>();
```

Comment: Either `CreateAs` or `MakeAs`. Anyway, definitely best one yet. Also, if the arrays cannot be put into the tuple, one can simply `std::forward_as_tuple()` them.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe splitting hairs, but `std::tie` should do the trick as well, we have lvalue references then anyway, and is even *shorter*...

Answer (score 2):

```
//C++ 11 SFINAE fold
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename ...Ts>
typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Ts)>::type       //I == end
    for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>&, const F&) {}


template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename ...Ts>
typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Ts)>::type        //I < end
    for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, const F& function)
{
    function(std::get<I>(tuple));
    for_each<I + 1>(tuple, function);
}

//C++ 17
template<size_t I = 0, typename F, typename ...Ts>
void for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, const F& function)
{
    if constexpr(I < sizeof...(Ts))
    {
        function(std::get<I>(tuple));
        for_each<I + 1>(tuple, function);
    }
}

//Client
for_each(std::tie(array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8, array9), 
    [](auto& array)
    { 
        for(auto* element : array)
        {
           element = new A();
           element->foo();
        }
    });
```